# Unity5 で作ったものを iOS Simulator でテストしたい

Tags: ios, xcode, unity3d

Unity で iOS 向けにビルドして、出来たXcodeプロジェクトを Xcode で開いてビルドすると、iOS Simulator にUnityのアイコンが表示されてアプリが起動します。でも、画面が黒い(紺色？)まま何も変化しません。
Unity で作ったものはテスト的に Sphere を一つとライトを一つ配置してるだけの簡単なものです。
別に WebGL 向けにビルドしてみたんですが、ブラウザで表示してみるとちゃんと表示されました。

一応、自分でも調べて以下のことをしています。
・Play Setting の SDK Version を Simulator SDK にする。
・Bundle Identifier を適当に書き換える。(「com.jp.unity2d」にしてます)

Comment: Unity 5.0.2, 5.0.1P4 などで試してみましたが Simulator では動かないようです。実機であれば動作するようです。

Comment: 参考として　監視
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304586/unity-3d-can-not-start-iphone-simulator